# For cycle with strings

Tags: c++

I have several files named for example name_a, name_b, name_c, anothername_a, anothername_b,... Now I would like to make a for loop, such as

```
for(i = a,b,c){
dosomething
}
```

Is that possible in C++, if so, how? I am a beginner in programming and so far I have seen only iterating over numbers.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to iterate through all the lines of the file?

Comment: Put them in a `std::vector<std::string>` and iterate using range-based for.

Comment: [to previous comment] No, those are file names (names of histograms, in fact) and I want to do something for them (set color etc.). I would like to have my code short, so I am trying to avoid doing it for each one of them separately.

Answer (score 3):

Store the names in a container(`std::vector` is a good default) and iterate over it.

```
std::vector<std::string> filenames = {"foo.bar", "apa.bepa", "cepa.baz"};
for (const auto& name: filenames)
{
    std::ifstream input(name);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With modern c++ you can almost do exactly what you want:

```
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    for ( const auto& file: { "name_a", "name_b", "name_c", "anothername_a", "anothername_b" } )
    {
        std::ifstream input( file );
    }
}
```